# Remove duplicates from array of objects based on condition using lodash

Tags: lodash

I have an array of objects as shown below

```
[
    {id:1,name:'abc',path:'canvas.abc'},
    {id:1,name:'abc',path:'public.abc'},
    {id:2,name:'def',path:'supply.def'},
    {id:3,name:'xyz',path:'package.xyz'}
]
```

expected output:

```
[
    {id:1,name:'abc',path:'canvas.abc'},
    {id:2,name:'def',path:'supply.def'},
    {id:3,name:'xyz',path:'package.xyz'}
]
```

The object with same id should be removed but only when it's path property is other than canvas
I want to remove duplicates based on id but I want the value which has canvas in the path
I want to use only lodash and not JavaScript

I tried with uniqBy of lodash but it keeps the first value always but I need the value which contains canvas in path because the array is coming from backend and the order might change.
Any solution using only Lodash

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected output that you want?

Comment: expected output added

Comment: *"only lodash and not JavaScript"*  you know, lodash is a library implemented in javascript, don't you.

Comment: What happens if you have an addtional object with `{id:1,name:'abc',path:'canvas.xyz'}`?

Comment: And what happens if you have duplicate IDs, but non of them has a path that contains "canvas"

Comment: Only lodash means I meant only using lodash methods and not JavaScript methods. I have to use only lodash methods for some other reason.

Comment: 1. The path will have to include the name field. So this {id:1,name:'abc',path:'canvas.xyz'} type of object will not be present, since name is 'abc' the path should have 'abc' it cannot be 'xyz'                                                                                                                   2. When there are duplicate id's definitely there will be an object with path that contains "canvas".